# How to set okta configuration dynamically?

Tags: spring-boot, okta, okta-api

Suppose Two different customer having their respective client-id,client-secretkey,okta-domain. Based on my research on okta, I found that these parameters are to be set in application.properties file. How to set these parameter dynamically so that customer should redirect to their respective domain login page?

Edit :-

```
customer 1:-
a)DOMAIN :- dev-1234.okta.com
b)CLIENT_ID :- abcd
c)CLIENT_SECRET_KEY :- efgh

customer 2 :- 
a)DOMAIN :- dev-5678.okta.com
b)CLIENT_ID :- hijk
c)CLIENT_SECRET_KEY :- lmno
```

Suppose I select customer 2 , so customer 2's data should be set as environment variables(values in application.properties or application.yaml) ,but in spring boot there isn't any way to set environment variable dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment variables to set the properties for your respective apps. For example:

```
OKTA_OAUTH2_ISSUER=https://{yourOktaDomain}/oauth2/default \
OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID={yourClientId} \
OKTA_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET={yourClientSecret} ./mvn spring-boot:run
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, Can you please check edit part of question , I think you didn't understood my problem

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Dhanraj, I'm not fully understanding your question, but Spring Boot has many options to configure variables. This is [briefly covered here](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot#configure-your-properties) and more [in-depth here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

I'd recommend looking at [Spring Cloud Config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config) too.

I've also seen folks write a custom Java Agent to configure System Properties before Spring loads (but this is *sort of* what cloud config does anyway.)